# Guzzle 6 multipart issues with Laravel

Tags: php, file, api, laravel, guzzle

I'm trying to upload a file to a RESTFUL Api through Guzzle in Laravel.
I get the file in my controller perfectly and store it locally before sending it to the api.
But of course, it doesn't want and i can't figure out why...

```
$path = fopen(Config::get('bts.ajaxCall').'temp/' . $filename, 'r');

$params['file'] = [
   'name'     => 'file',
   'contents' => $path,
];
```

Here are my parameters i'm sending via the request :

```
   $response = $this->connecter->requestUpload($url, ['file' => $params['file']], [], 'POST', false);
    $data = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());
```

This is my request function

```
public function requestUpload($url, $parameters = [], $headers = [], $requestType = 'POST', $debug = false)
{
    $user = Auth::user();


     $role = 0;

    return $this->client->request($requestType, $url, [
        'multipart' => $parameters,
        'auth' => (!is_null($user) ? [$user->email, Session::get('api_token')[0]] : null),
        'headers' => [
            'X-Product' => isset($headers['product_token']) ? $headers['product_token'] : Config::get('bts.product_token'),
            'Accept-Language' => isset($headers['language_code']) ? $headers['language_code'] : 'en',
            'X-Role' => $role,                
            'User-Agent' => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
            'X-Disable-Translation-Id' => true
        ],
        'debug' => $debug,
        'decode_content' => false,
    ]);
}
```

And this is the response i get from the api when I dump the input file i get

```
  object(stdClass)#762 (1) {
  ["request"]=>
  object(stdClass)#760 (0) {
  }
}
```

I've tried already so many setup for my request. I followed the guzzle docs and it doesn't works, i reach to have my file params but empty.. I checked my fopen and the link i'm sending in is right i got the image i want.

I'm becoming to despair of finding the solution.

Comment: Change second sending parameter's value from `['file' => $params['file']]` to `$params['file']` and see what happens.